# Check if a stream ends with a newline

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream, eof

I want to check whether a stream (in practice an ifstream) ends with a newline. I have come up with this:

```
bool StreamEndsWithNewline(std::basic_istream<char> & the_stream)
{
    if (the_stream.peek() == EOF) {
        the_stream.clear(); //clear flags set by peek()
        return false;
    }
    std::string line = "blah";
    while (std::getline(the_stream, line)) {
       // ...
    }
    return line.empty();
}
```

The idea being that if the last line of the stream has a `\n` ending character, the while loop will do one additional iteration (because eof has not been reached) in which the empty string will be assigned to the line argument.

The special case of an "empty" stream has to be treated separately.

It seems to work on windows (vs2010). Can I do it this way in general?

Comment: File streams are required to end with a newline. This test will detect a stream that either has **only** a single newline or ends with **two or more** newlines.

Comment: A text stream that does not end with a newline is not a valid input stream in C or C++. Input operations on that stream are not required to handle it sensibly.

Comment: So with

std::stringstream the_stream("");
the_stream << "hello!";

is the_stream illegal input?

I believe this is what I get if I read in a file (using ifstream) which does not end with a newline.

Comment: @PeteBecker A file can end with anything it likes in either C or C++, and ditto both a file stream and a text stream. Both `std::getline()` and `fgets()` behave correctly if a final newline isn't present.

Comment: @EJP - whoops, too strong. From the C standard: "A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. **Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.**" 7.21.2/2. So read your documentation.

Comment: Do not use the in_avail. It only show the available amount of characters for a non blocking read (0 == next read may or may not deliver characters)

Comment: @DieterLücking `the_stream.peek() == EOF` better?

Comment: @DieterLücking I want the method to handle any stream object, also if it's empty. So I need some kind of test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; Yes, this is guaranteed to work, unless the stream is initially empty.

---

There are two bits to consider: the `fail` bit and the `eof` bit. `std::getline` does, from [string.io]:

> After constructing a `sentry` object, if the
>   sentry converts to true, calls `str.erase()` and then extracts characters from is and appends them to `str` as if by calling `str.append(1, c)` [...] If the function extracts no characters, it calls `is.setstate(ios::failbit)`

And `sentry` does, from [istream::sentry]:

> Effects: If `is.good()` is `false`, calls `is.setstate(failbit)`. Otherwise, prepares for formatted or unformatted input. [...] If `is.rdbuf()->sbumpc()`
>   or `is.rdbuf()->sgetc()` returns `traits::eof()`, the function calls `setstate(failbit | eofbit)`

So given all of that, let's walk through two examples:

---

Case 1: `"hello\n"`. The first call to `getline()`, `the_stream.good()` is true, we extract characters up through the `\n`, the stream is still `good()`, and we enter the body of the loop with `line` set to `"hello"`.

The second call to `getline()`, the stream is still `good()`, so the `sentry` object converts to true, and we call `str.erase()`. Attempting to extract subsequent characters fails, since we're done with the stream, so the `failbit` is set. This causes the return `getline()` to convert to false so we don't enter the body of the loop a second time. At the end of the loop, `line` is empty.

---

Case 2: `"goodbye"`, no newline. The first call to `getline()`, `the_stream.good()` is true, we extract characters until we hit `eof()`. The stream `failbit` isn't set yet, so we still enter the body of the loop, with line set to `"goodbye"`.

The second call to `getline()`, the construction of the `sentry` object fails because `is.good()` is false (`is.good()` checks both the `eofbit` and the `failbit`). Because of this failure, we don't go into the first step of `getline()` which calls `str.erase()`. And because of this failure, the `failbit` is set so we again do not enter the body of the loop.

At the end of the loop, `line` is still `"goodbye"`.

---

Case 3: `""`. Here, `getline()` will extract no characters, so the `failbit` is set and the loop is never entered, and `line` is always empty. There are several ways to differentiate this case from case 1:

- You could, up front, [`peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) to see if the first character is `traits::eof()` before doing anything else.
- You could count how many times you enter the loop and check that it's nonzero.
- You could initialize `line` to some sentinel non-empty value. At the end of the loop, the line will only be empty if the stream ends with the delimeter.

Comment: Re the `hello\n` example, yes, I agree I will get a single string, but the while loop will do an additional iteration because eof is not reached. And in this iteration I get an empty string assigned to the string parameter. So to me it seems I do not need the explicit eof check.

Comment: @Jens No, you don't. The next call to `getline()` will end up with a failed stream, so you don't enter the loop.

Comment: I agree that I don't enter the loop, but `line` will already be assigned a new value before entering the loop, no?

Comment: @Jens Yes, it will be an empty string as `getline` is called twice.

Comment: @Jens Here's a more thorough answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver `getline()` will be called twice regardless.

Comment: @Barry Thanks. Also, I think I need to handle the special case of an "empty" stream (that is, `std::stringstream a("")`) separately. I have edited the example.

Comment: @Jens Sure, not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works.

However, you may try seeking the stream and test the last character only or discard the characters read:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

bool StreamEndsWithNewline(std::basic_istream<char>& stream) {
    const auto Unlimited = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
    bool result = false;
    if(stream) {
        if(std::basic_ios<char>::traits_type::eof() != stream.peek()) {
            if(stream.seekg(-1, std::ios::end)) {
                char c;
                result = (stream.get(c) && c == '\n');
                stream.ignore(Unlimited);
            }
            else {
                stream.clear();
                while(stream && stream.ignore(Unlimited, '\n')) {}
                result = (stream.gcount() == 0);
            }
        }
        stream.clear();
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "empty\n";
    std::istringstream empty;
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(empty) == false);

    std::cout << "empty_line\n";
    std::istringstream empty_line("\n");
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(empty_line) == true);

    std::cout << "line\n";
    std::istringstream line("Line\n");
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(line) == true);

    std::cout << "unterminated_line\n";
    std::istringstream unterminated_line("Line");
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(unterminated_line) == false);

    std::cout << "Please enter ctrl-D: (ctrl-Z on Windows)";
    std::cout.flush();
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(std::cin) == false);
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Please enter Return and ctrl-D (ctrl-Z on Windows): ";
    std::cout.flush();
    assert(StreamEndsWithNewline(std::cin) == true);
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```